# How to call tiny_mce.init from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce

I know almost nothing about javasrcipt, but I do know I should be able to do this.

I have several different tinymce.init calls that I would like to make.  They work fine if I load them in the page's head but not if I move them to an external .js file. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following?

My page file header:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/load_tinymce.js"></script>
</head>
```

And my external file (load_tinymce.js):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "StandardEditBox",
    theme: "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none",
    forced_root_block: false,
    height: "50",
    encode: "xml",
    theme_advanced_resizing: false,
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onSaveContent.add(function (i, o) {
            o.content = o.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
            });
    }
});

tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "CommentsTextBox",
    theme: "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none",
    forced_root_block: false,
    height: "150",
    width: "580",
    encode: "xml",        
    theme_advanced_resizing: false,
    setup: function (ed) {
            ed.onSaveContent.add(function (i, o) {"&apos");
        });
    }
});
```

I feel like there should be something else in my .js file but I don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your `script` `src` is actually correct.

Try using the following:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/load_tinymce.js"></script>
```

This will load absolute from the root. Assuming your Scripts folder is at root level.

I removed the `..` from your `src` - as this is telling the page to look one folder back, relative from itself, for the `scripts` folder.

**UPDATE**

Change your src to:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/load_tinymce.js"></script>
```

Removed the `/`

Also, if you haven't done so, install Firebug for firefox. It will help you pin down the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks, but the Scripts folder is one folder back from where the page is located. Just to be sure, I tried this anyway and it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you verified it's actually loading? you could put something like `alert("Loaded");` in one of the files, before your `.init` - if this doesn't show when you load the page then your `src` is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks again, Darren. It's very odd. I added the alert. It never showed. However, I know the file is pathed correctly because when I look at the page source, FireFox shows the <Script src="..."> as a link.  When I click on the link, it opens the correct file.

Comment: Where did you put the alert? Outside of your init methods? Where do you have your `script` tags; between the `<head></head>`? can you show the folder structure you have for your site? Does FireBug show you any errors? - assuming your using FireBug? the fact the alert didn't fire tells me the src is wrong.

Comment: I put the alert in the load_tinymce.js file right at the top, above the init methods. Script tags are inside the <head></head> tags as shown above. The folder structure isn't mine to show, but suffice it that Script and TestPages (where the aspx pages are) folders are both first level directories in the project folder.

Comment: The text file was corrupt. Darren, your insistence it was the src helped me find the real problem.  Thanks.